# How to make onEdit(e) run on protected sheet? Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart != 7 && e.range.columnStart != 8 || e.value <= 0) return;
  let d = new Date();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.value == null){
      e.range.offset(0,-2).setValue(null);}
      else if (e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.value != null) {
      e.range.offset(0,-2).setValue(d);}
      else if (e.range.columnStart == 8 && e.value != null) {
      e.range.offset(0,-3).setValue(d);}
}
function Lock(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var protection = sh.protect().setDescription('Lock');
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me).setUnprotectedRanges(sh.getRange("I2:I").createTextFinder("^(?!Done).*$").matchEntireCell(true).useRegularExpression(true).findAll().map(r => r.offset(0, -3, 1, 3)));
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()){
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);}
}
```

- After running 2 functions. I edit in column 7 or column 8, will put the current date in the specified cell (column 5 in sheet), and will lock the range if `I2:I` has the value `Done`.
- Everything works great with owner. But collaborators who are authorized to edit the spreadsheet cannot, `onEdit(e)` cannot run (error : You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to disable protection if you need to edit). Because function `Lock()` protected the sheet leaving only those cells where column `I2:I` is not `done`.
- Is there any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that in your situation, to use the simple trigger might be the reason of your issue. So, how about the following modification? In this modification, the function name is changed from `onEdit` to `installedOnEdit`, and the installable OnEdit trigger is installed to the renamed function.

#### From:

```
function onEdit(e){
```

#### To:

```
function installedOnEdit(e){
```

And also, [please install the OnEdit trigger to the function `installedOnEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). And, please test it again.

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)